# django authentication .htaccess static

Tags: python, django, apache

In my app users can upload files for other users.
To make the uploaded files accesible only for the addresse I need some kind of static files authentication system.

My idea, is to create the apache hosted directory for each user and to limit access to this derectory using .htaccess.

This means that each time new django user is created, I need to create a directory and the appropriate .htaccess file in it. I know I should do it using post_save signals on User model but I don't know how to create the .htaccess in the user's directory from python level. Can you help me with that?

Or perhaps you have better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use python to rewrite the .htaccess automatically?
2. Use a database with users and use a Apache sessions to authenticate?

Comment: 1 & 2: Could you be more specific? 
How do I create .htaccess and add a specific user (suppose I have username and password in variables)
What to do you mean by "use Apache sessions"

Comment: Most authentication is done by validating the username + password from a database, e.g. MySQL, then creating a session through `session_start()`.

Comment: this solution is also better if you want to serve a folder, with a mini-site, for example, just like a plain old html with css on the side.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have an PrivateUploadedFile object that has a field for the file and a m2m relation for any Users who are allowed to read that file? Then you don't have to mess with Apache conf at all...

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
import hashlib

def generate_obfuscated_filename(instance, filename):
   hashed_filename = hashlib.sha1(str(filename)) #you could salt this with something
   return u"your/upload/path/%s.%s" % (hashed_filename, filename.split(".")[-1]) #includes original file format extension



class PrivateUploadedFile(models.Model):
  file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_obfuscated_filename)
  recipients = models.ManyToManyField('User')
  uploader = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name="files_uploaded")

  def available_to(self, user):
     #call this as my_uploaded_file_instance.available_to(request.user) or any other user object you want
     return user in self.recipients.all() #NB: not partic. efficient, but can be tuned
```

Comment: I have such thing, but I does not solve the problem. Notice that the file must be uploaded to public directory to be accessible from outside. I can verify if the user is the recipient in the view, but the file is still accessible for everyone.

Comment: Ok, why don't you obfuscate the filename then with a hash - i'll edit the code above to reflect this

Comment: Though I appreciate that I'm giving you security through obscurity, rather than a proper authentication-based solution

Answer (score 0):

Came across this [django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile#readme) which can be used to serve static files. Might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have Django handle authentication and authorization as normal, then use Apache's `mod_xsendfile` to have Apache handle sending the actual file. Remember to have the files uploaded to a place that cannot be accessed directly, ideally outside Apache's document root.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384145/django-with-mod-xsendfile-unable-to-download-complete-file) has a good example of how to implement this behaviour, but it basically boils down to setting `response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path` in your view.

[django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile#readme) does the same thing, but for several different web servers (and convenience shortcuts), and [django-private-files](http://django-private-files.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) is the same, but also implements `PrivateFileField`

Answer (score -1):

Add a view that controls the authentication of the user, and serve the file via [django's static files serving tools](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/):

```
def get_file(request, some_id):
    # check that the user is allowed to see the file
    # obtain the file name:
    path = path_from_id(some_id)
    # serve the file:
    return django.views.static.serve(request, path, document_root=your_doc_root)
```

This is a perfectly secure solution, but perhaps not ideal if you serve an enormous of files in that way.

Edit: the disclaimer on the django page does not apply here. Obviously, it would be inefficient to serve *all* your files with `static.serve`. It is however **secure** in the sense that you only serve the files to the users that are allowed to.

Comment: Logically it does the trick, but as you pointed out, there might be some efficiency issues

Comment: Well that's only if you serve a massive amount of files in this way! If I were you I'd implement that and reconsider it only if you can measure a performance impact. You know, "premature optimization is the root of all evil". ;-)

Comment: Why do you say this is "perfectly secure" when the page you link to has a huge disclaimer saying: "Using this method is inefficient and insecure. Do not use this in a production setting. Use this only for development."

Comment: @Daniel sigh... I knew someone would react on that disclaimer

Comment: +1 Not sure why you were voted down, as this seems to be the best solution for the OP and it avoids the ugliness of trying to generate Apache conf files with Django/Python.

Comment: -1 I don't think you understand the disclaimer. `static.serve` is insecure because it's not thoroughly tested for buffer overflow exploits, handling malicious headers, *etc.* Your point that the view handles authentication isn't relevant.